# Does this hold for three numbers

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, inequality

If $a\ge b\ge c\ge0$, does it hold that $\sqrt[3]{\left(a-b+c\right)^{2}}\ge\sqrt[3]{a^{2}}-\sqrt[3]{b^{2}}+\sqrt[3]{c^{2}}$?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: In the OPs defence - two answers in the space of half an hour compared to zero in 12 hours!

Answer (score 2):

You want to know if $f(a-b+c) \geq f(a) - f(b) + f(c)$ for $f(x)=x^{2/3}$ and all arguments positive.  This would be true if $g(t) = f(t + a-b) - f(t)$ were decreasing function of $t$, because the inequality can be written as $g(c) \geq g(b)$.  But that is easy to check.

Answer (score 1):

Consider one case of $a = b \ge  c \ge 0$. Both sides are equal, and the inequality holds.

Now, partial differentiate $\sqrt[3]{(a-b+c)^2} - \sqrt[3]{a^2} + \sqrt[3]{b^2} - \sqrt[3]{c^2}$ with respect to *a*.

$$\frac{2}{3}(a-b+c)^{-\frac{1}{3}} - \frac{2}{3}a^{-\frac{1}{3}}$$
$$=\frac{2}{3\sqrt[3]{a-b+c}} - \frac{2}{3\sqrt[3]{a}}$$

Show this partial derivative is positive (because $-b+c$ is negative), and you are done.